# How to Write data from FPGA to DDR3 memory without PS Logic

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise, register-transfer-level

I'm using zynq7000 family fpga, i want to write data from my fpga to micron ddr3 sdram memory without using PS logic (only using PL) I'm new to memory based designs may i get any help to design the logic using PL or any references.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to look at [this](https://medium.com/@caglayandokme/extending-the-memory-limits-of-microblaze-with-an-external-ddr-6c896e75c218) tutorial

Answer (score 1):

The biggest question is this: how is your "micron ddr3 sdram" physically connected to the FPGA? Is it pinned out for the PS-side? Or the PL? There are dedicated pins on the FPGA just for PS side memory. Now, if you absolutely **must** have PL logic interface with PS memory, then you can open an AXI port on the Zynq PS side to allow PL logic to get at the PS memory space. That's the only way to do it.

On the other hand, if the DDR is correctly pinned out to PL, then you can use the Xilinx Memory Interface Generator (MIG) IP core to build the PL-side logic to interface with it. See [here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/mig_7series/v4_2/ug586_7Series_MIS.pdf).